# Can't create relationships in SQL Server diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to create a database diagram. I've dropped in the tables that already have foreign key relationships; in addition, all the tables have primary keys. However, when I try to drag and drop from either table onto the other, I get the following error popup:

> Primary key or UNIQUE constraint must be defined for table 'Results' before it can participate in a relationship.

Again, both tables have primary keys. The database was imported via Microsoft's SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access tool to preserve relationships and keys. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results](
    [Result_AN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Detail_AN] [int] NULL,
    [Drug] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LDrug] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Lab_Result] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MRO_Result] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Confirm] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [CutOff] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Quant] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Screen] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Unit] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [Scrn_Result] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SSMA_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Results$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Result_AN] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: can you post the tables definition?

Comment: Using the diagram tool to create relationships is a bad way of doing it. You should learn the syntax and code these things. The error message you are receiving is pretty clear. You don't have a primary key or a unique index on your Results table. That means you can't use its values as part of a foreign key in another table.

Comment: Sounds like you think the table has a primary key, but it doesn't.

Comment: @SeanLange I wouldn't call it a "bad way of doing it"

Comment: @Lamak - your are right. Saying it is bad sort of indicates it might produce incorrect results which is not accurate. But using the visual tool to build RI is not a good approach as it doesn't force the user to learn the pretty simple syntax and also prevents providing a meaningful name to them.

Comment: Highlight the column which you want as a primary key and right click and select primary key. Did you know you can change the columns that are shown on the diagram by right clicking a table and selecting view options, this allows you to specify whether a column for say identity is shown etc.

Comment: Oh and the Foreign Key must have a relationship to the Primary Key of the referenced table

Comment: Thanks, @Lamak. Please see table above. It has a primary key.

Comment: @Alex Not enough info, please post both tables definition and you can also post a screenshot of how you are trying to create the foreign key

Comment: Alex, did you make sure the data in the table doesn't violate the foreign key constraint?  I have had cases where I tried to create a FK in a diagram and got a misleading error message and the culprit was data in the foreign key column that didn't match up with a primary key.  

(And I always create my FK constraints in a diagram, I get plenty of typing writing sprocs...)